AWS ALB does not include Keep-Alive timeout in response header
[1]. I am observing that the Apache HttpClient library that we are using expects this Keep-Alive: timeout  in the header to keep the connection in the pool alive, but as the AWS ALB that we are calling is not returning this header the client keeps the connection active forver (while ALB Closes it after 1 hour)
[2]. I am trying to debug an ALB behaviour that abruptly closes HTTP1.1 client connection (Client has an idle connection check so it does not take a stale connection from pool, also checked the on-the-fly request does not take more than a minute -while is idle conn timeout in ALB, to give repsponse from the backend server ). Is there a way to check why this happens in ALB
I am manually setting the KeepAlive (absolute and an overriden strategy which keeps the connection for 5 mins) in Apache HttpClient (4.5.x) to address [1], but still curious to know why ALB does [2]
